# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError even after everything compiles good

Tags: java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I started looking into Java's JNI feature. I followed this [tutorial][1]. So my class goes like this :

```
    package me.gagan.pheonix.natve;
    public class HelloJNI {
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("hello");
        }
        private native void sayHello();
        public static void main(String... args) {
        new HelloJNI().sayHello();
        }
    }


HelloJNI.c file like this:

    \#include <jni.h>
    \#include <stdio.h>
    \#include "me_gagan_pheonix_natve_HelloJNI.h"
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
       printf("Hello World in native C!\n");
       return;
    }
```

My directory structure is:

```
<pre>
C:.
├───bin
│   ├───me
│   │   └───gagan
│   │       └───pheonix
│   │           └───natve
│   │               └───HelloJNI.class
│   ├───resources
│   │   └───hello.dll
│   ├───me_gagan_pheonix_natve_HelloJNI.h
│   └───HelloJNI.c
└───src
    ├───me
    │   └───gagan
    │       └───pheonix
    │           └───natve
    │               └───HelloJNI.java
    └───resources
</pre>
```

I also added

```
    -Djava.library.path=C:\Gagan\workspace\Pheonix\bin\resources
```

But still error is coming. Any idea what is going wrong. Followed each step correctly.
Following commands worked for me

```
    gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c

    echo %JAVA_HOME%
    C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

    javah -verbose -jni -classpath . me.gagan.pheonix.natve.HelloJNI
```

EDIT:

Exception encountered is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: me.gagan.pheonix.natve.HelloJNI.sayHello()V
    at me.gagan.pheonix.natve.HelloJNI.sayHello(Native Method)
    at me.gagan.pheonix.natve.HelloJNI.main(HelloJNI.java:12)


  [1]: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html
```

Hi anybody having any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package me.gagan.pheonix.natve;
public class HelloJNI {
...
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
```

You've changed the package name after you generated the .h file with `javah`. Do it again, and adjust the function name in the .c file accordingly, to agree with the declaration in the .h file.

Comment: Aah nice catch, thanks i am trying and will update. Thanks EJP